# variable assigning to a similar variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

New to stack overflow and new to the language. I have some confusion on how to read this code, trying to learn the logic of it. If somebody can explain it will highly appreciate it.

```
$relationships = $member->relationships()
    ->whereIn('type_id', $this->getRelationshipTypesFor(['daughter', 'son']))
    ->with('member2.gender')
    ->get();
```

I'm confused if $member is assigning the relationship() which the variable $relationship? or is it from a constant Laravel function.
I'm a bit lost on how to read this. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to explain it with following code.

Assuming you have an model Person, which can have several Dog models. What you are doing, is calling to relationship between Person and Dog, and filtering it by the type of the Dog.

The function $this->getRelationshipTypesFor is just local func of class you are writting code in.

Eager loading ->with('member2.gender') means that Person model has relationship called member2, which has gender relationship. Honestly it's strange that the gender is relatioship there, but we don't know what is under the cover ¯_(ツ)_/¯. In example bellow I will name it as simple "dad" relationship.

```
// Person.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\Dog;
use App\Models\Dad;

class Person extends Model {
    public function dogs() {
        return $this->hasMany(Dog::class);
    }

    public function dad() {
        return $this->hasOne(Dad::class)->where('id', $this->dad_id);
    }
}
```

Then the query for this model is:

```
$person = Person::find($id);

$people = $person->dogs()
            ->whereIn('breed', $this->getBreeds()); // for example response of $this->getBreeds can be ['bulldog', 'poodle']
            ->with('dad')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so meaning the $member is accessing relationship() function from my example and the $relationship will hold the value? Am I on the right direction? Thanks

Comment: In your example `$member` is instance of Model. By calling `relationships()` you create query (Builder), connect some model to it (maybe `Relationship.php` model). Then you call whereIn, which way you are adding `where` props to query builder, same get builder back. WIth `with()` you eager load another nested relationship (that way it executes one sql query, instead of executing it each time you access `$member->member2->gender`) , same get back query builder instance. And finaly by calling `get()` you execute sql, and get back collection of models

Answer (score 1):

This is a so-called [fluent interface](https://betterprogramming.pub/what-is-the-fluent-interface-design-pattern-2797645b2a2e). A fluent interface is an object with this special property: most methods of the object have the same return value - the object itself. So if you call any of these methods, you know that the return value is the same object again - the same instance of the same class.

In your example, the `$member` object has these methods:

- `relationships()`
- `whereIn()`
- `with()`
- `get()`

The `$member` calls its method `relationships()`, which returns Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder instance. Now it calls `whereIn()` on it, which returns inself, and then it calls the `get()` method, which returns Collection object.

Comment: Well, the answer almost right. This is laravel Eloquent orm, which allows to work with database in OOP way. So relationships(), whereIn(), with() returns 
query builder Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder instance. While get() return laravel collection

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was pretty sure the snippet was from some ORM, but I decided to focus on the question how to read the code. Your answer provides important context by explaining what the code actually does. This big-picture view would make my answer too complicated.

Comment: I really appreciate this, you have all my thanks.